# How do you create a view in which users can assign tasks to themselves?

Tags: users, nodes, forms

**What I want to do.**

- A user clicks on his profile page.
- A view displays that shows a list of completed tasks.
- A task consists of a list of check-boxes (a checklist) and a "pending
  and finished" dropdown.
- The user should also be able to create a task for himself, selected
  from a list of checklists.

**This is my solution so far**

- Create a content type "checklists"
- create a role reference field
- create the checkbox field
- create a view with CONTEXTUAL FILTERS to show the tasks assigned to
  the user

**Ive also tried a few modules**

- checklist
- QA Checklist
- SEO Checklist

*But they dont seem to have the features i want.*

Am i going in the right direction?

> Flags also looks promising - It looks like you can create a flag(button:create task) and then use actions or rules to create the node and reference the user automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally got something right.**

Its actually quite easy, you can do it with just views and one module

1. Install http://drupal.org/project/userreference_url
2. Create a field "User reference" with widget "Reference from URL"
3. Create a view to display nodes with relationship to user.
4. Enable the button to create referenced node in the module.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following modules,

[To do list](http://drupal.org/project/to_do) for Drupal 6 only

> Offers a content-type for a simple To do list. It can be used for anything that needs to be done: getting milk at the store, reminding yourself to update a profile, telling your users to vote on a poll by a certain date...

and [myTinyTodo](http://drupal.org/project/mytinytodo) - Available for D6 & D7

> A simple way to manage your todo list. This module is based on myTinyTodo.

Otherwise you can do the same system with your current approach

Comment: myTinyTodo is almost what I need. But didn't see a way to add checklists.